# flexbe wont show source code

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

When I try to use the flexbe_app to show source code of a state in Statemachine Editor, I get the following error [image: terminal error message]

I've followed this tutorial http://philserver.bplaced.net/fbe/download.php and also installed ros-bridge and ran rosdep.

I run things with roslaunch flexbe_app flexbe_full.launch

I can run the first tutorial, so things seem okay enough.

I think I've located the line of the error in ui_panels_stateproperties.js, l:677, and I think it might be either

(1) a problem of trying to locate the default editor (?), but flexbe_app does open gedit when I ask to edit code from the main window,

(2) a path problem where my states are not really created properly as files or something is not being initialized(??)

Unfortunately I never used js, so I don't know what else to look for.

Thanks very much for the help!

Edit:
I've rebuilt and sourced the workspace without generic_flexbe_states and the error seems to be the same. I can still see the different generic states when I try to "Add State", so I think maybe I am not loading them (?)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/310698/flexbe-wont-show-source-code/) by [fbelmonteklein](https://answers.ros.org/users/32656/fbelmonteklein/) on ROS Answers with karma: 140 on 2018-12-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-12-14**:
Could you please attach your images directly to the question? I've given you sufficient karma for that.

Thanks.

**Comment by [fbelmonteklein](https://answers.ros.org/users/32656/fbelmonteklein/) on 2018-12-14**:
Oh, thanks! Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you for your question!

The "View Source" should normally work without any additional configuration and as you correctly pointed out, you can change the editor command in the Configuration page in case you want to use a different editor than gedit.

As answered in your [Github issue](https://github.com/FlexBE/flexbe_app/issues/29), this was a bug due to a recent change and it is fixed now. Thank you for reporting!

---

Originally posted by [Philipp Schillinger](https://answers.ros.org/users/24945/philipp-schillinger/) with karma: 321 on 2018-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fbelmonteklein](https://answers.ros.org/users/32656/fbelmonteklein/) on 2018-12-19**:
Solved. Thank you!